# String not being added correctly in C++

Tags: c++

I've spent about 3 hours trying to figure this out by searching Google and other threads and haven't found a solution that is working for me.

I'm creating an inventory program and I've run into a pretty unique problem.
When I run the data files I'm given, the program throws a lexical_cast boost exception. I know the exact line that is throwing the exception, however it doesn't make sense as to WHY the exception is being thrown.

If I take the data from the text file I'm given and copy and paste it to a brand new text file, the program runs it perfectly fine. 100% functional. However, when I run the original data files, the year string is suddenly deleted when it's added.

```
std::cout << year << std::endl; //prints out year perfectly
std::string date_str = "";
date_str += year; // <-- Here's the Problem. //Gets added as an empty string
std::cout << date_str << " Year should be added" << std::endl;
date_str += month;
std::cout << date_str << " month added" << std::endl;
date_str += date;
std::cout << date_str << " date_str" << std::endl;
std::cout << year << std::endl;

//The following line is what is throwing the exception:
boost::gregorian::date d = boost::gregorian::from_undelimited_string(date_str);
```

The print out is:

```
2010
 Year should be added //Notice the space at the beginning where year should be.
05 month added
0501 date_str
2010
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::bad_lexical_cast> >'
what():  bad lexical cast: source type value could not be interpreted as target
Abort (core dumped)
```

EDIT: There was a \r character at the end. I added an erase method call to year and the code works perfectly now.

Comment: Can you [edit] this so the code compiles?  Otherwise, people will have to ask you about the code that you've omitted from your question.

Comment: I would suggest you to use an `std::ostringstream` instead of concatenating whatever you concatenate to an `std::string`

Comment: It's possible you have some non-printing control characters in your `year` string - e.g. a trailing carriage return, which would mean `"2010\r Year should be added"` would be printed on the terminal, which would plausibly appear as `" Year should be added"`. Why not output `year.size()` so you can see whether there's just the 4 visible characters?

Comment: Thank you for the fast replies! I wanted to keep the code simple because it's a massive file and this is the only line in question. It does populate everything correctly.

As for year.size() it prints out to 5, so I guess that means a \r is present at the end. I'll run a remove character fast.

Comment: It works now! Thank you! I added a year.erase(4,1); just before it gets added.